# Command Delegate is not working calling from Swift to Objective C

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, cordova

I'm trying to bridge Swift 5 and the existing Objective c Function. Typically the Cordova request hits the Swift layer which inturn calls Objective C and returns back the result to Cordova. During compilation, I'm getting this error

```
       NSLog(@"Result : %@ ", result);
       CDVPluginResult* pluginResult;
       pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:result];
       // Below line throwing "No known class method for selector 'commandDelegate'"
      [[self commandDelegate] sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `commandDelegate` property is an *instance* property, not a *class* property. The clue is in the error "No known class method" - the code above must be currently in a class method (denoted by `+` in ObjC), but the `commandDelegate` property can only be referenced from an instance method (denoted by `-`). `self` in this context is a reference to the class itself, rather than an instance of the class.

Make sure the enclosing function is an instance method (if that's what you need). Also make sure that your plugin is implementing the `CDVPlugin` interface (`@interface MyPlugin : CDVPlugin` in your plugin's header file), otherwise you won't be able to access the `commandDelegate` property.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, let me check this.

Answer (score 0):

Making it var to globals.

struct Globals {
static var sampleCommandDelegate: Any?
}

Comment: That's one way of solving it, but it seems a bit of a hack. It may be perfectly acceptable for your use case though. I'd suggest taking the time to refactor the code so that you don't need to reference the command delegate statically. What are you doing in your method that means it has to be a class method rather than an instance method?

Comment: @CPR Yes, you are right and agree. This fix will be for the time being. I have to revisit :)